# Bring forward/send backward option in jquery draggable?

Tags: jquery, draggable

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I've just started learning javascript. I have created a drag/drop game using jquery draggable: http://www.vwardv.com/doll8.html

Now I need to improve it so that users can:

1. use a button to bring the item forward (over other items)
2. use a button to send the item back (behind other items)

In order for this to work effectively, there will also need to be an indicator of which layer is currently selected (e.g. a bounding box or something).

Would be really grateful for any help you can offer. I've put the code below in case you need it.

Thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".mydraggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="items">
<img src="bodies/palepd.gif">
<img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/top.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="mydraggable">
</div>
</body>
```

**update**

Thanks for your help.

Okay, so (as I'm a complete beginner) the first thing I did is to read the referenced links, and then research and understand the code line by line. This is my understanding of what the codes does:

On click of img variable maxZindex is declared and assigned value of 0.

Then iterate over all images to find the highest z-index any image has. The iteration is as follows:

- the variable z is declared and assigned the same value as the z-index of the image being iterated.
- if the value z is not a number it is given the value 0 (is this just to prevent errors?)
- if the value of z is greater than var maxZindex then maxZindex will be assigned the value of z.

Then assign the clicked image the value of maxZindex + 1.

This code brings the selected image to the top of all images.  But what if you just wanted to bring it one layer higher? And what if you only wanted this to happen when an image named #upbutton was pressed? I guess the code would be something along the lines of:

- some code which would 'select' the image, showing a bounding box - only deselecting when another image is clicked. I've been doing research but I have no idea how to do this.
- then code to increase the selected image's z-index by one upon the event of a mouse-click on upbotton. Here is my attempt:

  ```
   $("#upbutton").click(function() {
      var z = parseInt($(*Selected image*).css('z-index'));
     $(*Selected image*).css('z-index', z+1);
     });
  ```

Am I even vaguely on track here?

I've tried using the code offered but I've obviously input it into the existing code incorrectly. Can anyone advise on what I've done wrong (code below)?

Thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".mydraggable" ).draggable();
});

$("img").click(function() {

// find the z-index of the top-most item
var maxZindex = 0;
$("img").each(function() {
    var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
    if(isNaN(z)) z = 0;
    if(z > maxZindex) maxZindex = z;
});

//assign a z-index greater than the current max to the clicked item
$(this).css('z-index', maxZindex+1);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="items">
<img src="bodies/palepd.gif">
<img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/top.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="mydraggable">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The code you've written for bringing the clicked image one level up is somewhat correct, but needs some more mods. Suppose you have 3 images with z indices 3, 6 and 9. Lest say you clicked on the one with z-index=3. Setting its z-index to 4 wont be of much help. You'll need to find the next higher z-index and add one to it. And then apply the result to the clicked div.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How would you specify the next highest?

Comment: Please see my updated answer in which i've detailed the logic for moving the selected item one level down. You can take that and reverse the logic to easily move it one level up. Let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The code to move the clicked item one level down will be something like:

It basically involves:

1. Getting all elements with a z-index lower than the selected item's
2. Getting the element with the highest z-index (let's call this targetElem) among the ones with lower z-index than the selected item's
3. Swapping the z-index of selected item with targetElem

You can reverse the logic for bring one level up.

Hope it helps.

```
// selected item
var div = $('.selected');

// get selected item's z-index into myZ
var myZ = parseInt(div.css('z-index'));
if(isNaN(myZ)) myZ = 0;

// get all elements with a z-index that myZ
var lowerZElements = [];
$('.z').each(function() {
    var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));  
    if(!isNaN(z) && z < myZ) lowerZElements.push(this);
});

// get the element with the highest z-index among the 
// ones with lower z-index than myZ
var targetZ = 0;
var targetElem = null;
for(var i=0; i<lowerZElements.length; i++) {
    var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));  
    if(z > targetZ) {
        targetZ = z;
        targetElem = this;
    }
}

// swap the z-indices with targetElem
$(this).css('z-index', targetZ);
$(targetElem).css('z-index', myZ);
```

---

Suppose you want to bring the item forward on click:

```
$('img').click(function() {

    // find the z-index of the top-most item
    var maxZindex = 0;
    $('img').each(function() {
        var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
        if(isNaN(z)) z = 0;
        if(z > maxZindex) maxZindex = z;
    });

    // assign a z-index greater than the current max to the clicked item
    $(this).css('z-index', maxZindex+1);

});
```

Comment: I suggest to make the cloth items match the size of the model image you are using. :)

Comment: Thanks very much. I've done my research and have tried to understand this line by line. But I can't get it to work! I've edited my question with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the [css z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

and using [jquery to modify it](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. Now not sure how to use a seperate button to increase the z-index of an img. I've edited my question accordingly.